# How does GameRanger works?

Tags: c#, lan, emulation

I want to know how does [GameRanger](https://gameranger.com) make players appear in the Multiplayer's LAN section of the games. Because in my observations there is no signs of Virtual Network Adapters (or pcaps like [WinDivert](https://web.archive.org/web/20220417042956/https://www.reqrypt.org/windivert.html)) being used unlike it's counterparts like [Hamachi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogMeIn_Hamachi).

<s>It is possible in C#?</s>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, after a lot of researches...

As you know GameRanger, Tunngle (RIP), Radmin VPN and Hamachi enable their users to play games that support multiplayer over LAN with each other over internet. GameRanger stands out from rest of the solutions in that it doesn't depend on user to install a [TUN interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN) or any kind of solution that makes you expose your whole machine to just play a game.

Instead, GameRanger provides the developers who want to have their game supported on GameRanger to use a SDK. I found that out when a macOS version of a particular game had their game shipped (perhaps accidentally) with [debug symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_symbol) unstripped. On Windows, GameRanger comes with a DLL file that it [injects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection) into the game's process at runtime which [hooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking) Windows [Socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) APIs and forwards packets to other players.

As for establishing [P2P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer) connection between two players; GameRanger performs [NAT hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)) possibly using [STUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) to do so. It also tries [UPnP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play); and if that fails, it asks user to manually [forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) 16000 UDP port on their routers.

Comment: Got any links ?

Comment: @Trass3r For what?

Comment: @Trass3r Google and IDA.